# Appium Error: Could not get Xcode version

Tags: xcode, testing, mobile, automation, appium

Appium error when trying to launch test on eclipse.
I have installed Xcode 6.4 and it should work but it doesn't.

```
error: Could not determine Xcode version:Could not get Xcode version. /Library/Developer/Info.plist does not exist on disk.

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
info: [debug] Error: Could not get Xcode version. /Library/Developer/Info.plist does not exist on disk.
    at getVersionWithoutRetry$ (lib/xcode.js:115:11)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcode/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcode/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:294:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcode/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcode/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.runBound (domain.js:267:12)
    at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcode/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:89:39)
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcode/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:100:28
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not get Xcode version. /Library/Developer/Info.plist does not exist on disk.)","origValue":"Could not get Xcode version. /Library/Developer/Info.plist does not exist on disk."},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 470.776 ms - 286 

error: Could not determine iOS SDK version
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not get Xcode version. /Library/Developer/Info.plist does not exist on disk.
```

Eclipse code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Uicatalog {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        File f=new File("/Users/afiliptsov/Application to study/ui-catalog-app.zip");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "8.4");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 5s");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, f.getAbsolutePath());
        IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

I was using command line Appium. To resolve the issue you have to switch Xcode to the proper path.

The following command will help:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

If you have installed Xcode app in a different location, give that path instead of /Applications/Xcode.app.

Comment: If above command doesn't work. Try restarting Appium and run again.

Comment: Thanks! @LongNguyen

Comment: I was having a similar issue with Fastlane: *Could not determine installed iOS SDK version.*, after running the `fastlane snopshot init` command. This solution worked well and resolved my issue too.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, the problem was that the path to XCode was in Appium was set to something like "xcode/library/developer/commandlinetools". 
Setting the **correct path to Xcode** (in my case: "MacintoshHD/Applications/Xcode 2") in the advanced iOS Settings solved the problem for me.(Xcode 7, Appium 1.4.13)

Comment: The Setting is in Appium GUI

Comment: BTW, where did you get Appium 1.4.13? Current version is 1.2.6 https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.2.6.

Comment: @strizhechenko 1.2.6 is the version of Appium Desktop, which has it's own version numbering. With 1.4.3 I was refering to the used Appium standalone version, which is now at 1.7.1 see: https://github.com/appium/appium/releases

Answer (score 3):

First i reset it using 
**sudo xcode-select --reset**

and then used
**sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app**

Note: just make sure you set correct path to Xcode (Application->Xcode)

Answer (score 2):

Run sudo xcode-select -r before open appium desktop

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using Xcode version 10 and It is not support appium because appium server problem, you can back to `Xcode ver 9.` or use `appium beta`:

```
npm uninstall -g appium && npm install -g appium@beta
```

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons

1. When you have two versions of XCODE.
2. When your XCODE path is not correct.

1st problem you can resolve by following steps

- If your XCODE is running then close it & Appium as well
- Move unnecessary version to bin.
- Reset the XCODE path : **sudo xcode-select --reset**
- Set the correct path : **sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app**
- Start the XCODE and Appium.

2nd problem you can simply resolve by closing the XCODE and run the above two commands

- Reset the XCODE path : **sudo xcode-select --reset**
- Set the correct path : **sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app**

If problem not resolved yet, then check the Appium version and install the compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to resolve this is to move the Xcode application into your Applications folder on mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 11**

Check whether Command Line Tools of respective Xcode Version are installed or enabled

Answer (score 0):

After setting proper xcode version with

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

You should **RESTART** the appium server