# Appium iOS - Could not determine Xcode version

Tags: ios, selenium, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium Desktop(v1.6) to run my application on real to inspect elements. 
When I am trying to do this, I am getting the below error

```
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not determine Xcode version: Could not find path to Xcode by symlinks located in /var/db/xcode_select_link, or /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_link
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at getAndCheckXcodeVersion$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/utils.js:52:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
```

This is my capability which I am adding in appium.

```
   {
      "platformName": "iOS",
      "platformVersion": "11.0.3",
      "deviceName": "Sumit's iPhone",
      "udid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "app": "/Users/sumit/Documents//MyApp.ipa",
      "automationName": "XCUITest"
    }
```

When I am trying to run the command on terminal I am getting my vesion of xCode.

```
MAC:~ sumit$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 9.1
Build version 9B55
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724616/appium-error-could-not-get-xcode-version)

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 9.1 *is not supported* by Appium server 1.6

First step is try with **latest appium server** 1.7.2 beta:

```
npm uninstall -g appium
npm install -g appium@beta
```

If you still face the issue, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453829/could-not-find-path-to-xcode-by-symlinks-located-in-var-db-xcode-select-link-o) to check xcode simlinks

Answer (score -1):

Resolution :- type in terminal :- 
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app